# Will the speed of object be the same for observers with different speeds if the speed of the object is closer to the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames, observers

If we assume an object X traveling at a speed $V$ that is a bit  slower than the speed of light (let's say 1000 miles/sec.), what will be the difference in the observations of the speed of object made by two observers A & B, where:

- A is not moving at all with respect to the object under observation
- B is moving with a velocity $c-V$ in the direction of the moving object X, i.e., both are moving towards each other on the same imaginary line.

Please excuse if the question seems too lame for you.

Comment: B is the object under observation? Your problem statement is confusing.  Maybe the unusual punctuation contribute to this.

Comment: Are you saying that A observes the speed to be zero..?

Comment: @nasu the object under observation is X .two observers are just observing the relative speed

Comment: Shouldn't B travel with velocity B in the direction of X instead of c-V?

Comment: @abbu What is  the reference frame in which the speed V is measured?

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for the awkward formatting - I'm new to the site.)

First, let's get rid of our privileged observer who gets to decide who is "really" traveling at what velocities. Instead, let's define our system in terms of relative velocities. If I understood your paragraph correctly, your system has:

- Let the velocity of $X$ measured by $A$ be $v_{AX}$
- Let the velocity of $B$ measured by $A$ be $v_{AB}$
- Let the velocity of $A$ measured by $B$ be $v_{BA}$
- Let the velocity of $X$ measured by $B$ be $v_{BX}$
- Given **$v_{AX}$** and $v_{AB}$, solve for the other terms.

In the Newtonian paradigm, which approximates the relativistic paradigm for $v\ll c$, we first need to find $v_{BA}$. This is easy: it's just the negative of $v_{AB}$, since we switched our point of view to the opposite direction. Now we just add the vectors.

$$v_{BX}=v_{BA} + v_{AX} = v_{AX} - v_{AB}$$

In the relativistic paradigm, we need to account for the speed of light being the same for all observers. You can find one derivation [here](https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/relavelocities.htm).

On a line, we can simply replace each vector with its matching scalar.

$$v_{BX} =  (v_{AX} - v_{AB})/(1 - v_{AX}\cdot v_{AB} / c^2)$$

In 3D space, we'd need to break each vector $v_{BX}$, $v_{AX}$, and $v_{AB}$ up into their $x$, $y$, and $z$ components, compute each separately, and then take their vector sum to obtain our vector $v_{BX}$.

As a side-note, 1000 miles per second (about 1600 km/s) isn't very close to the speed of light (about 300000 km/s).

Comment: Welcome! We can use MathJax to format equations here. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation Another good reference is TeX Commands available in MathJax
https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm MathJax / $\LaTeX$ has a ton of features, but it doesn't take long to master the basics.

Comment: @g s so if we are asked about the relative velocity between A and B based on the speed of the X observed by them , will they (a and b )be at 0 relative velocity ,ain't this be wrong to say them being at rest with respect to each other

Comment: @abbu, we can do the same thing with any set of two observed velocities.

Comment: For two observed velocities and three observers A, B, X: First, obtain the correct reference frames. If you're trying to find v{AB}, you need one of the observed velocities to be in A's reference frame and one of the observed velocities to X's reference frame. Then you can break them down into their x, y, and z components and factor out the unit vectors to reduce them to a scalar, apply the lorentz conversion $$v_{AB} =  (v_{AX} + v_{XB})/(1 + v_{AX}\cdot v_{XB} / c^2)$$, then sum the x, y, and z components to obtain a vector.

Answer (score 0):

$v_{XA}=0$. The value of $v_{XB}$ will be the result of the relativistic velocity addition of velocities $V$ and $c-V$, which is greater than $c-V$ and less than $c$.